# Weird behaviour of `zip` utility on OSX?

Tags: encryption, macos, python

Today, [I was reviewing someone's Python code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/160827/61966), and while I was testing it, I spotted a weird / unsafe behaviour (bug?!).

1. I've created a password-protected zip file, by issuing the following commands on the terminal:

   ```
   touch test.txt
   zip -e test.zip test.txt
   ```
2. After I set up a password, say: "youllneverguessmypassword", I've continued working on OP's code. So far so good.
3. When I ran the code I found that there's another correct password, different from the one I set, to the zip archive I previously created.

This is how a part of the python script looks like:

```
import itertools
import string
import time
import zipfile

ARCHIVE_PATH = 'test.zip'

def bruteforce_attack(nbcharmax):    
    alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation

    t0 = time.time()
    for i in range(1, nbcharmax):
        for j in itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=i):
            password = ''.join(j).encode()

            try:
                zipfile.ZipFile(ARCHIVE_PATH).extractall(pwd=password)
                t1 = time.time()
                print('Password found: {}\nTime spent: {} seconds'.format(password.decode(), t1 - t0))

                return True
            except RuntimeError:
                pass
    return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bruteforce_attack(5)
```

Running the above code lead me to the following password: `j=`, which obviously is pretty different from the one I set, **but it works**.

What's the reason behind this ? Why is it happening ? Is it a bug ? I'm getting a bit worried because I set up a 25-characters long password and I've found a 2-char solution in under 0.2 seconds.

Comment: this has nothing to do with python. I'd say that both passwords gave by chance the same hash and it worked. Funny. Maybe better posted in some other SE site (cryptography)?

Comment: See https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/zipfile.py#L525-L568; zip-file encryption isn't particularly strong. It's CRC based, so yes, there will be colliding password values that produce the same CRC.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I never said it has something to do with Python, I just gave the whole set up I've used to find this ;P

Comment: Martijn confirmed what I suspected: you can generate the same CRC using 2 different passphrases. You _tagged_ the question with "python", so I guess there's a relation :)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5YYrENl36WE is relevant here.

Comment: looks like than the `youllneverguessmypassword` is too optimistic. :) - just kidding... ;)